# How to retrieve text from DIV tag using xpath extractor for jmeter

Tags: html, xpath, jmeter, load-testing

I am writing some load tests using Jmeter. Now I want to retrieve DetailIds, modeOrKey, and previouskey="d9d3f801-12fa-439f-924a-3ca3d9b4182c" from the tag. I am using XPATH extractor to extract it. Can you please guide how to retrieve that data from the following tag.

```
<div id="divBasket" class="basket" previousaction="reload" previousdata="DetailIds=5528e3e6-be52-4fe5-97be-ac2ba8f60956,426e0bfb-cd08-4420-8af4-364e352a7b79&amp;modeOrKey=dd18682c-40bc-4f5e-9fc7-09d8ce77566f" previouskey="d9d3f801-12fa-439f-924a-3ca3d9b4182c">
```

Please guide.

Comment: I can't help you on the Jmeter part, but to retrieve "DetailIds=5528e3e6-be52-4fe5-97be-ac2ba8f60956,426e0bfb-cd08-4420-8af4-364e352a7b79&amp;modeOrKey=dd18682c-40bc-4f5e-9fc7-09d8ce77566f" you can use `.//div[@id="divBasket"]/@previousdata` that you'll have to URL-decode and split by `key=val` pattern; and for `previouskey` value, use `.//div[@id="divBasket"]/@previouskey`

Comment: sorry, you should not need to decode the value of `@previousdata` HTML entities like `&amp;` will be decoded automatically from the XML representation

Answer (score 0):

I think the [CSS/JQuery_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) is easier.

CSS\JQuery Expression: `div#divBasket`

Then you can get the attribute one by one. you still need to split `DetailIds` and `modeOrKey` by yourself.